# How to random array without repeat in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim r As New Random
Dim A(2) As String
A(0) = "A"
A(1) = "B"
A(2) = "C"
MsgBox(A(r.Next(0,3)) & "," & A(r.Next(0,3)) & "," & A(r.Next(0,3)))
```

I want to see in the result one of the following rows:

```
A,B,C
A,C,B
C,B,A
C,A,B
B,A,C
B,C,A
```

Comment: What do you mean "without repeat"?

Comment: You need to shuffle the array then access each element one at a time, or just use String.Join()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the array in a random order and then go to 0, 1, 2.

```
Dim r As New Random
Dim A(2) As String
A(0) = "A"
A(1) = "B"
A(2) = "C"

A = A.OrderBy(Function() r.Next).ToArray()

MsgBox(A(0) & "," & A(1) & "," & A(2)
```

Comment: you need to have it being `A = A.OrderBy(Function() rnd.Next)`

Comment: @SophairkChhoiy: if an answer solved your problem you should accept it so that other people will know the problem is solved.